# Gps tracking, how to handle locations with overlapping radius

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, gps, asp.net-web-api2, geofencing

So i am working on a gps tracking application. Location updates are sent from mobile devices and received by a web api. We then check if the user is within a locations radius and if so we check them into that location. However some locations have a large radius, this allows us to account for users with poor gps accuracy.

You can see an example below, each location has a radius of 100. And there all overlapping. The icon is the central point and circle is as representation of the locations radius in meters.

[image]

So in order to checkin we do a distance calculation from the users gps point to the locations, and check them into the closest location. I understand this is quite a specific question and what im looking for is guidance from people who have worked on a similar problem, just a push in the right direction. For example a kalman filter can be applied to improve the accuracy of a users location updates, is there some form of machine learning/ probability calculation i can implement to detect which location the user is more likely to be checking into.

Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: if a gps location is in more than one area - could you determine the check-in based on distance to each central point?

Comment: You can find very useful articles about GPS accuracy in Uber's team technical blog : https://eng.uber.com/tag/gps/

Comment: @DawoodAwan yes your right. When we select locations close to the user we order by distance, and then check the user into the closest location. However the issue with that is the user may not want that location they may want the location next to it. But the overlapping then interferes with this.

Comment: @MojtabaTajik Thank you i will have a read through it

Comment: do you give the user option to select check-in location?

Comment: yes we thought about that, however we want it to be handle silently in the background. With minimal user interaction on the app side.

Comment: what is a check-in location? is it a restaurant, hotel, parking space?

Comment: It is user defined. It is essentially just a gps point but the actual real world location could be anything. but yes it is usually a building the user would be entering for a period of time.

Comment: What "check-in" means in this context? Is it somehow time-based (you have booked hotel or report to visit a doctor) or trully just been there, (probably) done that? Knowing ahead where you are supposed to be can help you filter-out the points. How do you know that somebody wants to check-in to place1 but not place2 when they are closer to place2? How can you even know? ...gps has some accuracty, your position query frequency is limited by battery consumption... you can maybe predict future position and take advantage of that fact that GPS signal was lost (inside building).

Comment: Prioritize locations and select the geofence according to the priority.